# Laravel Stapler Get url with '\'

Tags: php, laravel

i'm developing with Laravel. I will use Codesleeve Stapler and it work in local.
But when i deployed my app. The image doesn't display in firefox.

when i write this

```
<img src="{!! $cat_tampon->image_categorie->url('medium')!!}" />
```

I get

```
<img src="img/img_categorie/1/medium/\PostaMetal.jpg" />
```

When I delete '\' into the url, image is displaying.

my model

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array()){
        $this->hasAttachedFile('image_categorie', [
            'styles' => [
                'medium' => '250x250'
            ],
            'default_url' => '/img/img_categorie/0_default/:style/image_non_dispo.png',
            'url' => '/img/img_categorie/:id/:style/:filename',
        ]);


        parent::__construct($attributes);
    }
```

I don t know how to resolve that, can you help me pls

PS : It works on google chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. Not the best, i'm sure but it works.

I just use str_replace on the string.

like this

```
{!!str_replace('/\\', '/', $cat_tampon->image_categorie->url('medium'))!!}
```